# Python data manipulation string to dict and then data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I would like to convert this string  to a dictionary and then to a dataframe in Python.

```
string1 = "[{col1: val1,col2: val2,col3: val3,col4: val4}]"
```

I want the data frame like

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
val1 val2 val3 val4
```

Thank you for the feedback, here I am adding what I tried

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(string1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to evaluate the string so it becomes a dict, and then you can construct the dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: @Chad Eytan That's not a policy of SO (apparently). Have you ever tried entering the comment: "What have you tried?"

Comment: I have edited my question. I thought it is  a simple manipulation.